# How to read every nth row using Dask read_csv for fast multiple reading in multiple files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, dask

I'm trying to read in multiple CSV files into a single dataframe. While this works using list comprehension and Panda's concat function, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', etc....]
all_df = []
for filename in files:
    all_df.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
df = pd.concat(all_df)
```

I find this is too slow when files is a long list (e.g. 100s items).

I've tried using Dask which accepts list as input and has built-in parallelisation for speed, e.g.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df_dask = dd.read_csv(files)
df = df_dask.compute()
```

which gives ~2x  speed up.

However, for further speed up, I want the ability to only read in every Nth row of the files.

With Pandas, I can do this using a lambda function and the `skiprows` argument of read_csv. e.g.
`cond = lambda x : x % downsampling != 0` and in the loop, use, `pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=cond)`.

However, this doesn't work for Dask and the skiprows argument doesn't accept lambda functions. I can't pass in integers to skiprows since each file has a different length so exactly which rows to skip differs for each file.

Is there a fast solution? I'm thinking that some sort of operation to downsample that's compatible with Dask could be a solution, but not sure how to implement.

Is this possible please?

Comment: Have a look at the dask delayed interface, you could implement your pandas read with skiplines and then parallelize it using dask delayed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not quite sure how this would work though - I thought the speed up came from using Dask rather than Pandas for loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on @quizzical_panini's suggestion to use `dask.delayed`:

```py
import dask
import pandas as pd

@dask.delayed
def custom_pandas_load(file_path):
     # do what you would do if you had one file
    cond = lambda x : x % downsampling != 0
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, skiprows=cond)
    return df

[computed_dfs] = dask.compute(
    [custom_pandas_load(file_path)
     for file_path in files]
)

df_final = pd.concat(computed_dfs)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm afraid it doesn't work though. computed_dfs contains lists of data, not dataframes, so `pd.concat` returns an error. Also, there's no speedup from increasing downsampling here, whereas there is when using Pandas alone. Thus perhaps Dask is less efficient at handling skiprows?

Comment: Please treat the above code as a suggestion only, you will need to write and test the delayed function for your specific use-case. `dask.delayed` will generally not be more/less efficient at handling a specific function, it's only a means to parallelise a workflow, so the gains from parallelisation will depend on how many cores you have, as well as how the delayed function was constructed.

Comment: Ok thanks, in this case it looks like there's a penalty using Dask not a gain, as I'd then need to convert lists --> dataframes, adding more processing cost. Thanks anyway

Comment: No, I think there will be a gain if you skip a lot of rows. `computed_dfs` will contain a list of dataframes, but it should be fast/easy to concatenate them. If you are not getting a list of dataframes in `computed_dfs` then I would suggest running the delayed function on one/two files and ensuring it returns a dataframe.